# List fields in parameters from Fc list in script validation using arcpy in arcgis

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, parameters, python-toolbox, tool-validation

I am trying to list fields from a feature class list in script tool validation. First user selects the data frame from the list then FC populates in next box and fields of the FC in next box. I have code up to populating the FC list and working fine. but after that i'm trying list fields from the FC and getting error.

here is the code

```
import arcpy
class ToolValidator(object):
  """Class for validating a tool's parameter values and controlling
  the behavior of the tool's dialog."""

  def __init__(self):
    """Setup arcpy and the list of tool parameters."""
    self.params = arcpy.GetParameterInfo()

  def initializeParameters(self):
    """Refine the properties of a tool's parameters.  This method is
    called when the tool is opened."""
    try:   # this works
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')
        dflist = [df.name for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)]
        self.params[1].filter.type = "ValueList"
        self.params[1].filter.list = dflist
        del mxd
    except:
        arcpy.AddError("\nMust run this tool in ArcMap, not ArcCatalog")

    self.params[2].enabled = True

    return

  def updateParameters(self):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    has been changed."""
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')

    if self.params[1].value:
        self.params[2].enabled = True

        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, self.params[1].value)[0]
        # creates an empty dictionary
        if df:
            layerList = [lyr.name for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(df) if not lyr.isGroupLayer]
            uniqueList = list(set(layerList))
            uniqueList.sort()
            self.params[2].filter.list = uniqueList


# Up to this it working and problem is from below code


    if self.params[2].value:
        self.params[3].enabled = True

        df = str(self.params[1].value)   
        lyrList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)  
        for lyr in lyrList:  
            if lyr.supports("dataSource") and lyr.name == str(self.params[2].value):  
                for field in arcpy.ListFields(lyr.dataSource):  
                    uniqueList = list(set(field))
                    uniqueList.sort()
                    self.params[3].filter.list = uniqueList            


    return

  def updateMessages(self):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    return
```

Comment: This question/answer may help. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330672/deriving-field-parameter-from-table-parameter-in-python-toolbox

Answer (score 1):

There could be two issues here:

This line: `for field in arcpy.ListFields(lyr.dataSource):` this is returning a Field Object which you are adding to list which you then feed into your param[3]. I'm guessing param[3] is of type string? So you need to feed into you uniqueList `field.name`.

Also this line looks odd to me: `uniqueList = list(set(field))`. field is a field object which you are adding to a set then converting to a list. This list gets overwritten on the next loop of `for`. I think your logic is flawed here.